# Convolution UIImage with GPUImage framework

Tags: ios, image-processing, convolution, gpuimage

I'm trying to use GPUImage3x3ConvolutionFilter of GPUImage framework but is not working.

This is my code, I only get a white image.

```
- (UIImage *)convolution:(UIImage *)inputImage{

    GPUImagePicture *stillImageSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:inputImage];

    GPUImage3x3ConvolutionFilter *filter = [[GPUImage3x3ConvolutionFilter alloc] init];
    [filter setConvolutionKernel:(GPUMatrix3x3){
        {-1.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f},
        {-2.0f,  0.0f, 2.0f},
        {-1.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f}
    }];

    [stillImageSource addTarget:filter];
    [stillImageSource processImage];

    return stillImageSource.imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput;

}
```

I'm also try changing:

```
return stillImageSource.imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput;
```

for:

```
return filter.imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was due to a bug in the framework. Convolutions were also being applied against the alpha channel of the image, which resulted in a 0 alpha channel value in the the `[filter imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput]` case. I just committed code to fix this.

Note that `[stillImageSource imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput]` does nothing, because you can't grab the unprocessed images directly from a camera input. Also, I wouldn't use dot notation here, because `-imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput` is not a property of GPUImageOutput.